# How can I make html 5 audio continue HLS audio play when Android screen locks?

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

I'm playing HLS audio in Chrome Browser on Android using HTML 5 `<audio>`.

How can I get Chrome to keep playing a HLS stream on lock stream or when browser tab is inactive?

On iOS the stream will continue to play when the browser tab is changed or screen is locked, but it stops the audio on Android.

```html
<audio controls preload="meta">
    <source
        src="http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"
        type="application/x-mpegURL"
      />
</audio>
```

I even added mediaSession info to try and help it along.

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
if ("mediaSession" in navigator) {
    audio.onplay = function() {
        navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
            title: "TEST",
            artist: "ARTIST"
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android will play hls streams natively, but if you want the behaviour where it plays on the lock screen use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/)

```
let audio = document.getElementById("hls-audio");
let source = "http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"

if (Hls.isSupported()) {
  console.log("hello hls.js!");

  let hls = new Hls();
  hls.attachMedia(audio);
  hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
    console.log("video and hls.js are now bound together !");
    hls.loadSource(source);
  });
}
audio.onplay = () => {
  console.log("we can track events the same way with hls.js")
};
```